# How to confirm clicking on a link using jQuery

Tags: jquery, hyperlink

I have many links in a HTML-table, which delete corresponding row, when clicked (calling a PHP-script via GET parameter).

They all have a class **delete_row**.

How could I please display a **confirm('Really delete?')** dialog using jQuery, when such a link is clicked?

And of course prevent following that link when **No** has been selected in the dialog.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Try this.

```
$('.delete_row').click(function(){
    return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?");
})
```

Comment: Is event.preventDefault() not necessary here?

Comment: Not required, returning `true/false` will take care of it.

Comment: works great, how could I customize the message in the dialog box using for example a data-message attribute?

Answer (score 27):

Very simple and effective **one line** solution without using **jquery**:

```
<a href="to/your/path" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?');">Delete</a>
```

Comment: Work perfectly ;) Thank you

Answer (score 3):

you can use preventDefault method of the event object in the handler function:

```
jQuery('.delete_row').click(function(event){
     if(!confirm('Really Delete?')){
         event.preventDefault();
     }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a error!

Use this:

```
$('.delete_row').click(function(){
    return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also call another function after confirm like this:

```
<a href="to/your/path" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?') && yourOtherFunction();">Delete</a>
```