# jQuery confirm a link click

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to ensure that the user wants to delete an entry from out database.  I'd rather halt the action in the initial function than try and do it within the delete function because that just makes more sense.  At any rate, the site keeps skipping the confirm dialog box and just proceeds to delete the entry.  I'm not exactly sure whether its just a syntax error but I can't figure out why my jQuery isn't tripping.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js" ></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    ('a.confirm').click( function( event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr('href') ;
        var confirm_box = confirm( "Are you sure you want to delete this player?" );
        if( confirm_box ){
            window.location = url;
        }
    } );
});
</script>
<?php 
function roster_table()
{
    try{
        if( isset( $_SESSION['session_id'] )  )
        {
            $db = honneyconnect( ) ;  // db connection established
            if( mysqli_connect_error() )
            {
            throw new Exception( "Could not connect to the database") ;
        }
        $query = 'select * from roster' ;
        $players = $db->query( $query ) ;
        if( !$players  )
        {
            throw new Exception ( "Query returned zero results" ) ;
        }
        else
        {
            $number_of_players = $players->num_rows ;
            echo "<div id='player_table'>
            <table><th>Hells Canyon Honeys Active Skaters</th>" ;
            for( $i = 0; $i < $number_of_players; $i++ )
            {
                $row = $players->fetch_row() ;
                echo "<tr><td>".$row[0]."</td><td>".$row[1]."</td><td>".$row[2]."</td>
                <td><a href='http://localhost/honeysproject/editplayer.php?player_id=".$row[0]."'>Edit</a></td>
                <td><a class='confirm' href='http://localhost/honeysproject/deleteplayer.php?player_id=".$row[0]."'>Delete</a></td></tr>" ;
            }
            echo "<tr><td><a href='http://localhost/honeysproject/playerinfoentry.php'>Add Player</a></td></tr></table></div>" ;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception( "You are no longer authorized to view this document.  Please re-authenticate!<br>" ) ;
        session_destroy( ) ;
    }
    }
    catch( Exception $error ) 
    {
        echo $error ;
    }

}
```

Comment: Should `('a.confirm').` not be `$('a.confirm').`? And you are missing `)}` for your document.ready

Comment: The PHP is irrelevant here. Post your rendered HTML instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `$` when selecting the element via `(a.confirm).click(...)`.

Fix it like this:

```
$('a.confirm').click(function(event){
    //...
});
```

Furthermore, you can simplify your whole script via just using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('a.confirm').click(function(event){
         return confirm( "Are you sure you want to delete this player?" );
   });
});
```

Based on the returning value (`true` or `false`) the redirecting will be handled automatically.

Answer (score 1):

change `('a.confirm').click( function( event){`

to `$('a.confirm').click( function( event){`

Comment: And to add to this answer, @NoobWebDev, you can simplify your code a lot. See this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9044823/482115

Answer (score -1):

You are missing $ in selector ('a.confirm').
about the confirm dialog [this](http://myclabs.github.io/jquery.confirm/) probably should help you

Comment: What is wrong with the browsers confirm box?

Comment: no issue with it, wrong selector was used in the above code

Comment: $ is missing in code, $('a.confirm') should be used instead of ('a.confirm')